# Override default jasmine error message for matchers

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, bdd, jasmine

I want to show some custom error message when any matcher fails , suppose i call this

```
 expect(false).toBe(true);
```

obviously it would return false and error message would be

```
Expected false to be true
```

But here i want to show my custom message . Suppose i want to show

```
You are expecting a false but its true .
```

How to do this . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write custom matchers for this. Because the error message is hard coded in jasmine.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly what you want because it is not flexible, but it can handle your case.

There is undocumented feature on the expect - you can include a custom failure message:

```
expect(false).toEqual(true, 'this is my custom error message');
```

In your case:

```
expect(false).toBe(true, 'You are expecting a false but its true .');
```

Otherwise, create a custom matcher (http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html):

```
jasmine.addMatchers({
    customToBe: function() {
        return {
            compare: function(actual, expected) {
                var result = {};
                result.pass = actual === expected;
                if (result.pass) {
                    result.message = "You are expecting a " + expected + " and its " + actual + " .";
                } else {
                    result.message = "You are expecting a " + expected + " but its " + actual + " .";
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```